# Disable button until all form inputs are validated in React

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, frontend

I have this form in my code, I want to, after checking all validation and patterns, the form button to become enabled, but I don't know how I can put this in my form, or do I need to write any other functions and which way is most clean Code?

```
const [disable, setDisable] = React.useState(true);

  const [staff, setStaff] = React.useState({
    username: "",
    email: "",
    phone: "",
    password: "",
  });

  const [errMessage, setErrMessage] = React.useState({
    username: "",
    email: "",
    phone: "",
    password: "",
  });

const handleChange = (e) => {
    switch (e.target.name) {
      case "email": {
        if (e.target.value.toLowerCase().match(emailValidation)) {
          setErrMessage({ ...errMessage, email: "" });
          setStaff({ ...staff, email: e.target.value });
        } else {
          setErrMessage({
            ...errMessage,
            email: "It should be a valid email address",
          });
        }
      }
      case "password": {
        if (e.target.value.length >= 12) {
          setErrMessage({ ...errMessage, password: "" });
          setStaff({ ...staff, password: e.target.value });
        } else {
          setErrMessage({
            ...errMessage,
            password: "It should be at least 12 character",
          });
        }
      }
      default:
        setStaff({
          ...staff,
          [e.target.name]: e.target.value,
        });
    }
  };

return( <button disabled={disable}>Submit</button>)
```

Comment: Hi Negar! I pasted an answer; please check it and let me know!

Comment: Hi. at the very first level all my errMessage state are empty strings and like when we have no error and the button at very first level is enable because errMessage length all is zero.

Comment: I see Negar! Check my updated answer please, and let me know.

Comment: Handling form validations in react with bare javascript code is difficult . I recommend you using libraries like ```Formik``` or ```react hook form``` .

Answer (score 1):

Since you are tracking the errors in that `errMessage` state, you don't need an additional state for `disable`. It could be a simple constant you can add above and outside `handleChange`:

```js
const disable =
  Object.values(errMessage).filter((v) => v).length > 0 ||
  Object.values(staff).filter((v) => v).length !== 4;
```

```js
<button disabled={disable}>Submit</button>
```

This way, the button is disabled when there is an error message, or when one field is empty.